# React change navbar colour based on route

Tags: react-redux, react-router

I am new to react. I am using react-route-dom and . I would like to change the colour of my NavBar functional component when the route changes.

In my NavBar component I am using the HOC (connect) from react-redux and withRouter from react-router to get route props and information from my redux store.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        moduleCards: state.moduleCards
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(NavBar));
```

Here is a snippet of how I am getting route information to then find the moduleCard entry and get it's colour.

```
const NavBar = (props) => {
    console.log("Hello world?");
    const modules = props.moduleCards.find(c => `/${c.name.replace(/ /g,'')}` === props.location.pathname);
    const color = typeof modules !== 'undefined' ? modules.color : 'blue';
    return (
        <nav>
            <div className={`nav-wrapper ${color} darken-2`}>
```

The problem is that the colour does not change when I change route. Can you please help with how to trigger a render on my NavBar component? Or if there is a better way to handle this?

Here is my root App component.

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <NavBar/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
            <ModuleRoutes/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a snap shot of my store, this is where I am grabbing the colour from.

```
const initialState = {
moduleCards: [
    { id: 0, name: 'Client Register', icon: 'person', color: 'red' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Property Register', icon: 'domain', color: 'blue' },
```

The colour is blue on the home page and unless I refresh it remains blue. When I refresh it rerenders and the navbar gets its correct colour.

Comment: I guess - color is always 'blue'?

Comment: It is blue on "/", for any other route the colour remains blue until they refresh. If I switch to another route the previous hold until another refresh.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this @Sigex?

Answer (score 0):

In [documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/redux.md) they wraps component first with `redux` and then with `router`

I propose you change your:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(NavBar));
```

to this:

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(NavBar));
```